# App icon not visible when code is run

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I have created an android app using android studio. When i run my code on the IDE, its runs as expected on the connected phone. The problem is, it does not leave behind an icon on my phone to use it next time. I will again have to run from android studio to use the app. This was fine initially, i don't realize what made the icon vanish. The app is also present in the settings.
When i go to

> Settings->apps

i can very well find my app over there. It is not disabled. I tried uninstalling the app and trying again. It still doesn't give me the icon.
I cleared defaults, forced closed and tried everything possible. Nothing is helping me.

Please help.

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TwitterLogin"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_twitter_login" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.chillumapp.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/chillum"
                android:scheme="http" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NextActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_next" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="b1fe9f0c7d80c3c24879d634b199f2d0e474b4ba" />

    <activity
        android:name=".WebViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_web_view" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you specified an icon? Do you have the file ic_launcher in your mipmap folders?

Comment: Can you show your `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: Yes i do have ic_launcher in my mapmip.

Comment: i have added my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Rebuild the project and try again

Comment: Manifest seems to be Ok. May be something to do with launcher icon location.

Comment: It is in mipmap folder. I think that is the ideal place.'

Comment: Can you let me know if this string value has any value ? `@string/title_activity_twitter_login"`

Comment: <string name="title_activity_twitter_login">TwitterLogin</string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a different  for every intent that can launch your app. So one for the BROWSER category with your url data, and one for the LAUNCHER category.

From the [App Manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#ifs) Guide.

> Components advertise their capabilities — the kinds of intents they can respond to — through intent filters. Since the Android system must learn which intents a component can handle before it launches the component, intent filters are specified in the manifest as  elements. **A component may have any number of filters, each one describing a different capability.**

Your code would become something like:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="www.chillumapp.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/chillum"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Superb. Works fine now.

Comment: Can i also know how to change the app name? It shows the name as TwitterLogin.

Comment: look for "title_activity_twitter_login" in the file strings.xml